# WPF - FocusVisualStyle where do i apply it?

Tags: wpf, focusvisualstyle

I have a `UserControl` which basically wraps a `ListBox` like this -

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=Pages}"
             Background="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=Background}"
             BorderBrush="Transparent"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I need to set the `FocusVisualStyle` to `{x:Null}` to hide this functionality but no matter where i apply it, i still get the default blue selection color.  I've tried setting it on the ListBox, StackPanel and the Grid but to no avail.

Any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FocusVisualStyle applies the "marching ants" around the focused element, not the background color. To change the background color of selected ListBoxItems, do something like:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Value="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Value="Black"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>    
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kent is correct the FocusVisualStyle is only related to the Keyboard focus, when selected controls with the Tab Key.

If you are just trying to display a list without any Selection capabilities you may just be able to downgrade your ListBox to an ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=Pages}" 
  Background="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=Background}" 
  BorderBrush="Transparent" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <!-- others -->
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Ja, had a go with that but I'm rendering UIElements in the ListBox and they don't obey the ItemTemplate in an ItemsControl oddly.  Thanks for the help though.